# Create a map of connected nodes from a list of edges in $O(n^2)$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have a directed graph. It may or may not be a DAG.

I would like to create a map in $O(n^2)$ time to find all nodes that are accessible from a node on a directed path, where $n$ is number of vertices.

$G := $

```
A  —> B —> C
|          ^
v          |
D —————————
```

M = `create_map(G)`  //in $O(n^2)$ time

- M(A) should be {B, C, D}
- M(B) and M(D) should be {C}
- M(C) should be $\emptyset$

How is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried a DFS with white, gray, black color? the complexity is achieved because of $|E|\leq |V|^2=n^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the [Strongly Connected Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) graph (this can be done in $O(|E|+|V|) \le O(|V|^2$)). You can then calculate which nodes is reachable from every node naively in $O(|V|^2)$ from this graph.